# When the child class inherits the parent class, how can the original type be passed in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
public class Parent<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public class T data { get; set;}
}

public class Child : Parent<decimal>
{
}
```

**Error: The type "decimal" must be a reference type to be used as the parameter "T in a generic type or method "Parent"**

When the child class inherits the parent class, how can the original type be passed in?

Comment: You can't pass `decimal` in here because `decimal` is a value type an your generic constraint explicitly requires a reference type (`where T : class`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some errors, change `public class T data { get; set;}` to `public T data { get; set;}`

and if you want to use value types in this case change your code to this:

```cs
public class Parent<T> where T: struct
{
   public T data { get; set;}
}

public class Child: Parent<decimal>
{
}
```